# OAUTH_TOKEN not defined twitter

Tags: python, twitter-oauth

```
Patricks-MacBook-Pro-2:Autofollow-API patrickahern$ python sample_twitter_codes.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sample_twitter_codes.py", line 30, in <module>
    from twitter_follow_bot import auto_follow_followers_for_user
  File "/Users/patrickahern/Documents/Vault/Internal-Social/Autofollow-API/twitter_follow_bot.py", line 26, in <module>
    from twitter_info import *
  File "/Users/patrickahern/Documents/Vault/Internal-Social/Autofollow-API/twitter_info.py", line 1, in <module>
    OAUTH_TOKEN = "zzzzzzzzzzzz"-"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
NameError: name 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is not defined
```

Based on the feedback, it appears as though something is off about the second half of the OAUTH_TOKEN, but I've checked on my Twitter API multiple times and can't find anything wrong with it.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `"zzzzzz" - "xxxxxxxx"`? You can't subtract strings...

Comment: The oauth token is broken into 2 sections that are separated by a minus sign, the first being a series of numbers, and the second being a series of number and letters. I didn't want to publicly share the token, so I used z and x as variables to represent it, and wanted to highlight the fact that it was the second section of the oauth token that wasn't defined

Comment: Well, regardless of what you were trying to do, it didn't work. Your OAuth token needs to be defined in one single string, not two strings with a `-` between them, otherwise you'll get the error you're getting. Define it as `OAUTH_TOKEN = "zzzzzzzzzzzz-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"`, all in one piece, and you'll be all set.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Matt. There was no space between the owner ID and access token in the code, so I'm still not sure what the issue is. The Twitter info doc is currently saved in the following format (once again, with "x" replacing all sensitive info). Does anything look off here?

           OAUTH_TOKEN = xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
           OAUTH_SECRET = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
            CONSUMER_KEY = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         CONSUMER_SECRET = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
         TWITTER_HANDLE = xxxxxxxx

Comment: Looks fine to me. Just as long as each item is in a single set of quotes (double or single quotes doesn't make a difference) then the API should accept them.

Answer (score 0):

```
OAUTH_TOKEN = "zzzzzzzzzzzz"-"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

> NameError: name 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' is not defined

The error lies in your above treatment of generated Access Token for your Twitter App.

The Correct format would be:

```
OAUTH_TOKEN = "zzzzzzzzzzzz-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

i.e "-" hyphen is a part of the token and needs to be included in the string.